# How can I know when an user connected?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to know the last users connnected on a Ubuntu machine on an exact day and month. Also the days the root user connected. Thanks

Comment: If their session are still alive, you can run `who` to see when their session started.

Answer (score 0):

If it's recent, you can use the 'last' command.